# INSERT INTO SQL Server : Linked Server without specifying database in semi-fully qualified name

Tags: sql-server, ssms, migration, linked-server, synonyms

I have a server called `DEV`, a database called `Nus12345`, a linked server called `SnapshotDev`, a schema called `Snapshot`, and a table called `SnapshotPersonEmployee`.

On the DEV server, there are many other databases. On the linked server, there are the same databases as on DEV.

Right now I have a stored procedure that inserts into the table with

```
INSERT INTO Snapshot.SnapshotPersonEmployee
```

We are instead conceptually wanting to change to inserting into a table on a linked server by using

```
INSERT INTO [SnapshotDev].[Nus12345].[Snapshot].[SnapshotPersonEmployee]
```

My question is, can I insert into the table on the linked server **without** changing the stored procedure? Is there a way (like making a synonym) that will reference the table on the linked server with just

```
INSERT INTO Snapshot.SnapshotPersonEmployee
```

**EDIT**

I should add that this stored procedure appears once on every database, and that is why I want to try to do this without change the stored procedure. By not naming the database it allows us to keep one version of the stored procedure--one SP on each database, but they are all the same.

We are thinking of removing the `SnapshotPersonEmployee` table in the current (DEV) server from all of the databases. Would this help/hinder any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use SQL `synonyms` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552(v=sql.105).aspx

By doing that you'll have a full control behind the curtains, but please fully document it and be consistent. It is a nightmare to troubleshoot databases with synonyms.

As an alternative you can use dynamic SQL, it might be more transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to drop/rename the original table, then you can create a view with the same name instead, but pointing at the linked server.

So your view would be in the snapshot database (but please list your columns):

```
CREATE VIEW [Snapshot].[SnapshotPersonEmployee] AS 

SELECT * FROM [SnapshotDev].[Nus12345].[Snapshot].[SnapshotPersonEmployee]
```

Then you can insert into it as you would any other table.  This also lets you avoid synonyms which as Slava Murygin pointed out can be problematic to troubleshoot.